# Asset management tracking

Tags: audit, iso27001

I was tasked with getting all of our ISMS Assets documented to prepare for an ISO 27k audit. Right now I am using a spreadsheet and I would like to use something more... professional. It has way to much information to have in a spreadsheet and be easily understandable for people who didn't work on it. I though about using our inventory system, but it had its complications since its more focused on physical computers instead of things like intellectual property, or contract management.

Are there any applications out there that help manage this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Dell Kace, you can install clients on all your computers and it'll let you know the hardware information as well as software installed and all of those kind of things, pretty powerful. Of course it's not free and will take configuration and the like, but that's the professional level for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Looks like Kace is also physical assets only.